# @Transactional annotation working only when declaring in class

Tags: java, jpa

Need some help regarding Transactional annotation. So I have a class like this:

```
@Component
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class Inserter {
    public void saveAndCommit(Mapper mapper) {
       saveAll(...)
       ...
       DeleteManager.saveAll(mapper, this.containerRepository);
    }

    private <T, N> void saveAll(JpaRepository<T, N> repository, List<T> entityList) {
        if (entityList != null && !entityList.isEmpty()) {
            repository.saveAll(entityList);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's DeleteManager:

```
public final class DeleteManager {
    public static void saveAll() {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

My problem is: I was using the @Transactional annotation in saveAndCommit method, since this one calls all the others. But when calling DeleteManager.saveAll(...) I was getting the following error:

> Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

And I'm not sure why it only works when I add the annotation at the class level. Since I call all methods from saveAndCommit, shouldn't work like this as well?

Thank you!

Comment: what happens when you use `javax.transaction.Transaction` instead of the one provided by spring

Comment: Do you call `saveAll` only from `saveAndCommit ` or is it a separate call?

Comment: @aBnormaLz only from saveAndCommit actually :)

Comment: @Lino haven't tried yet. Is there any difference here? Thank you! :)

Comment: The issue is also happening ONLY when calling DeleteManager.saveAll(...)

Comment: Now I noticed that your `DeleteManager.saveAll ` is a static function, so maybe that's the problem. I flagged your question as a possible duplicate :)

Comment: @aBnormaLz thanks for doing this! Actually it's not working even moving the same method for the class but i guess it's better for me to create another topic with different details. Thanks again!